# I need the approach to solve this problem in python

Tags: python, string, loops, dictionary, conditional-statements

You get an integer which indicates the number of strings you get next. You have N strings where (N-1) strings follow the same pattern but one string doesnot follow the pattern. You have to find that odd string which doesnot follow the pattern and print it. Pattern varies in each case. Each string length may vary. Only one odd string is present in all the given strings.

Example :
INPUT :
4
ABCD
BCDE
CDEF
DGES

OUTPUT:
DGES

Please give me the approach to solve this.

Comment: Please provide the code in text form (in the question, not as an image), also name variables with meaningful names "d", "li" and so on are not the best choices to be honest.
Also please provide the output you got with your attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a list to store tuples of the form (query, pattern).

Once you have this list you just need to find which pattern occurs only once. In that way you can easily detect the "odd one out"

```
n = int(input())

qp = []

for _ in range(n):
    query = input()
    pattern = [ord(x)-ord(y) for x, y in zip(query, query[1:])]
    qp.append((query, pattern))

for q, p in qp:
    if sum(1 for _, _p in qp if p == _p) == 1:
        print(q)
        break
else:
    print('No unique patterns detected')
```